# Hexo blog CMS deployment to Heroku not working

Tags: css, node.js, heroku, content-management-system, hexo

Right now I am using a simple NodeJS CMS called Hexo to make a blog for my company.

Hexo's main website: http://hexo.io

Hexo's Github page: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo

So far it seems to be pretty nice, I got it running great locally and am in the process of getting the blog to successfully deploy to Heroku. However, that is where I am running into trouble!

Like Hexo's Docs say to do I....

1.

```
hexo generate
```

2.

```
hexo deploy
[info] Start deploying: heroku
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Fetching repository, done.
Everything up-to-date
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from git@heroku.com:bloglikethewind2.git.
[info] Deploy done: heroku
```

3. Yay, it deployed correctly and everything should be working.

Except when I go to my app (https://bloglikethewind2.herokuapp.com) all of the CSS seems to be gone! Then, when I go to the CSS file (https://bloglikethewind2.herokuapp.com/blog/css/style.css) all I get is:

```
Cannot GET /blog/css/style.css
```

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong for hours but am totally stumped. Anyone with some insight or can suggest a solution?

If it helps... I have made my source code open to the public @ [Zach's Github blog repo](https://github.com/djlovegrind/texasca-blog)

https://github.com/djlovegrind/texasca-blog

Comment: @user1483163 you mind taking a look at this for me? I would be super appreciative... I see that you have your Hexo blog running on Heroku just fine at http://jeffic.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was wrong after some more hours of puzzling and poking around.

The problem was inside my _config.yml file.

The line

```
root: /public/
```

This needed to be changed to....

```
root: /
```

And that was it! I will leave this Question & Answer up just in case it helps anybody else who makes the same blunder as I did :)